# UITableViewCell background colour different then what I inputted

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ipad, interface-builder

I'm having an issue where the iPad version of my app is giving me a different UITableViewCell background colour than the one that I've inputted.

Here is the colour of the background colour:

[image]

[image: The box in the bottom-right corner is showing the correct colour]

Here is the iPhone screen that is showing the correct background colour:

[image: As you can see, the background image of the UITableViewCell is the same as the colour in the previous pictures.]

And here is the iPad's screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the iPad's background colour is a very light colour of what I wanted. Granted, I inputted this colour before, but decided to change it to the colour that you see in the iPhone screen. If I change the background image, then it will only affect the background colour of the iPhone app. The only code that's affecting anything colour-wise in my app (in regards to the Table View Cell) is this:

```
    UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.40 blue:0.60 alpha:1.0];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;
```

I've tried disabling the above code to see if it's this that's affecting it, but it doesn't solve the issue. 
This has had me scratching my head all day, and I don't know why this is happening.

I'm using the latest version of Xcode and my app is targeted for iOS 8.0. The background colour was changed on the "Any Height; Any Width" class. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated. If needed, I can send a Dropbox link for the app.

Comment: Are you using Size Classes? If so you've probably customized your view for iPhone only and not for tablets.

Comment: I am using Size Classes, but the thing is that I changed the background colour on the "Any Height; Any Width" class. I've edited the question to show the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for iPad write down your code i.e.

```
UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.40 blue:0.60 alpha:1.0];
cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;
```

in `willDisplayCell` delegate.

I think This will helps you.

Comment: this works perfectly. don't know why iPads need this line when iPhones do not!